# Java Spring MySQL String Timezone column between two milliseconds

Tags: java, mysql, between

I got a stored Timezone date as String on a ***MySQL Column*** with the next format:

**2018-07-23T20:54:37.242Z** --> *start_date*

What I want to do is a ***Between*** two milliseconds(or dates) like this:

```
SELECT * FROM activity_entity WHERE start_date BETWEEN 1532322000000 AND 1532408399000
```

Else, I'm using **Java Spring Repository** as backend where I send the parameters like this:

```
Date since = new Date(accessRepPOSTInDto.getSince()); //1532322000000 gives Mon Jul 23 00:00:00 CDT 2018
Date to = new Date(accessRepPOSTInDto.getTo());//1532408399000 gives Mon Jul 23 23:59:59 CDT 2018

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM activity_entity WHERE start_date BETWEEN :since AND :too , nativeQuery = true)
ActivityEntity findBetweenDates(@Param("since") Date since, @Param("too") Date too);
```

Doing this **returns** *null*;

I thought MySQL can automatically format the two dates and the String column to do the Between but it looks like it doesn't.

Any help will be really grateful. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your native query, you need to explicitly cast the value of your varchar column to the proper date/timestamp to be evaluated by the between operator. This is how your native query should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM activity_entity WHERE STR_TO_DATE(start_date, '%Y-%c-%eT%H:%i:%s.%fZ') BETWEEN :since AND :too
```

Comment: Thanks for the answered @LuiggiMendoza i will try it, as a doubt, the :since and too should be used as **double 1532322000000** or **Date Mon Jul 23 00:00:00 CDT 2018**. Regards.

Comment: @ElíGiacomelli the parameters are `date` already, they don't need any cast.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE event >= ? AND event < ? ;  -- Using Half-Open approach where beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.
```

Java:

```java
myPreparedStatement.setString( 1 , Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_532_322_000_000L ).toString() ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setString( 2 , Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_532_408_399_000L ).toString() ) ;
```

## ISO 8601

> 2018-07-23T20:54:37.242Z

Text in this format is abiding by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. That standard is the best way to represent date-time values as text. But in a database you should be using a purpose-built data type, defining a column of type akin to the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. Search Stack Overflow for much more info.

The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```java
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2018-07-23T20:54:37.242Z" ) ;
```

## Count-from-epoch

You can convert your count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC using the `Instant` class.

```java
Instant start = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_532_322_000_000L ) ;
Instant stop = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_532_408_399_000L ) ;
```

Generate strings in standard ISO 8601 format used in your database column.

```java
String startStr = start.toString() ;
String stopStr = stop.toString() ;
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The old date-time classes that were bundled with the earliest versions of Java are bloody awful. Never use them. They have been supplanted entirely by the *java.time* classes.

## Half-Open

> What I want to do is a Between

The `BETWEEN` command in SQL should generally *not* be used with date-time values. That command is fully “closed” meaning both the beginning and the ending are *inclusive*.

Instead, for date-time work, it is generally best to define a span-of-time as Half-Open. In this approach the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. For example, students dismissed for lunch break from noon to 1 PM are expected back in their seats *before* the clock strikes 1 and the bell rings. Another example, a week starts on a Monday and runs up to, but does not include, the following Monday.

In SQL code, this means a query uses `>=`, `AND`, and `<`.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE event >= ?
AND event < ?
;
```

Since ISO 8601 format with the `Z` is chronological when sorted alphabetically, you can make this work with your ISO 8601 strings.

```java
myPreparedStatement.setString( 1 , startStr ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setString( 2 , stopStr ) ;
```

If you had used a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column type as discussed above, you would simply pass the `Instant` objects.

```java
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , start ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 2 , stop ) ;
```

If you really must use fully-closed approach, adjust the query operators `>=`, `AND`, and `<=`. Or call `BETWEEN`.

---

I am not a Spring user, cannot help you there.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).